# Connecting wifi to Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+

i have used wifi before and it worked but now only Ethernet works. ive tried the config file and switching wifi dongles but nothing. ive use sudo ifup wlan0 and get wlan0 not detected , but ifconfig show it there

Comment: See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) If you have a more specific question you need to provide details.

Comment: You should setup as before. What have you changed? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.